# Attempting to query a tagging object(many to many table)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables that i am trying to query:

**Mods**

```
mod_id
author
url
name
```

**Tags**

```
tag_id
tag_name
tag_url
```

**tags_to_mods**(mods & tags have many to many relationship)

```
ttm_id
tag_id
mod_id
```

Essentially i am trying to find the tag_name and tag_id related to the given mod_id.

How do i go about doing this? I am quite a newbie with SQL and have yet to attempt querying properly relational data like this. I assume that there is a better way to do it than what i have opted to go for.

my attempt at this (in pseudo(ish) code):

`x = SELECT tag_id FROM tags_to_mods WHERE mod_id = $mod_id`

`SELECT tag_name, tag_id FROM tags WHERE tag_id = x`

it gets the desired result but i have to query my table twice...

Comment: Is it possible to rearrange your tables?  It seems like having three tables would get tricky to keep everything correct and I think you can reduce it to two if you add mod_id to the tag table and vice versa.

Comment: @nick all of my access to the database is handled through hard coded statements, so i'm able to control exactly what i put in and when

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this(where $mod_id is the id of the Mod):

```
select tg.tag_name, tg.tag_id
from Tags tg
inner join tags_to_mods tm
on(tg.tag_id = tm.tag_id)
where tm.mod_id = $mod_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT m.author, m.name, m.url, t.tag_id, t.tag_name
FROM Mods AS m
INNER JOIN tags_to_mods AS tm ON tm.mod_id = m.mod_id
INNER JOIN Tags AS t ON t.tag_id = tm.tag_id
WHERE m.mod_id = $mod_id
```

Comment: Although i went with @Robert Rozas's answer, i appreciate your help!